# Assign numerical values to factor column

Tags: r

I posted this question a month ago and after updating R and Rstudio I am now encountering the same issue.

I am looking to convert factors to leveled numeric data.

So a column of Prox would read: Far, Far, Near, On, Far, Near, Far, Far, Near, Far.

I would like to assign numeric value to these factors, where
Far is 1,
Near is 2,
On is 3.

Using either of these codes below

`levels(Prox) 
 levels(Prox) <- c(1, 2, 3)`

OR

`Prox_df <- Prox_df %>%
  mutate(Prox_df = case_when(Prox == "Far" ~ 3,
                     Prox == "Near" ~ 2,
                     Prox == "On" ~ 1))`

resulted in NA coercions.

I have tried setting levels to these factors but this did not assign the numeric value. I need to use this leveled, numeric value for an ordinal model. If you have any suggestions please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base R solution:

```
Prox_df$Prox <- as.integer(as.factor(Prox_df$Prox))
```

Using data from @HNSKD (thank you):

```
Prox_df <- data.frame(Prox = c("Far", "Far", "Near", "On", "Far", "Near", "Far", "Far", "Near", "Far"), 
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `dplyr::case_when` should work fine.

**Data:**

```
Prox_df <- data.frame(Prox = c("Far", "Far", "Near", "On", "Far", "Near", "Far", "Far", "Near", "Far"), 
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

**dplyr::case_when**

```
Prox_df <- Prox_df %>%
  mutate(Prox_df = case_when(Prox == "Far" ~ 1,
                             Prox == "Near" ~ 2,
                             Prox == "On" ~ 3))
```

**dplyr::recode**

```
Prox_df <- Prox_df %>%
  mutate(Prox_df = recode(Prox, "Far" = 1, "Near" = 2, On = 3))
```

**base::factor**

```
Prox_df <- Prox_df %>%
  mutate(Prox_df = factor(Prox, levels = c("Far", "Near", "On"), labels = 1:3, ordered = TRUE))
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for responding. I had tried case_when(), which doesn't result in anything. Using recode() results in the error: unused arguments (Far = 1, Near = 2, On = 3), and using base::factor() does not result in any changes. I was looking to have a new column that shows as numerical (1, 2, 3) based on the factors (Far, Near, On), hope that provides some clarification.